# Word starting with P that indicates strengthening of a bond?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently writing a very much tongue in cheek book which involves ancestors bonding with newborns. There is something in my book that I currently refer to as Burial Soil that I'm trying to give a more scientific name for. Basically, it's what made the ancestral bond possible and can strengthen it when ingested.

Since it's tongue in cheek, I want something that has the same abbreviation AP as [Applied Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum), a literary device that makes the plot move forward.. The A is easy, I can use Ancestor or a derivative word for that, but the P is somewhat harder. I considered Plotinum or something similar and might use that if nothing better comes up here, but I'm hoping for something that is more indicative of bonding and/or strengthening of a bond. It should also preferably have earthy connotations, since it's soil.

Example sentence: 3300 years ago, an ancient urnfield was turned into Ancestral {Word here} in what we call the Gallitrix event, kickstarting our civilization.

---

After reading the answers, I decided to use "pactite" as the name for the material itself. Since the person who recommended the word pact didn't post this as an answer, I decided to accept the answer that mentioned "to permeate", because I could use this for another aspect of the central theme as well.

Comment: How about "pact"? "A formal agreement between individuals or parties"

Comment: @RobBland I think slightly modified to pactite, this is also a very good term. If you can post that as an answer, I could upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these two definitions of *[permeate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/permeate)*

> 1. to penetrate or pervade (a substance, area, etc)  *a lovely smell permeated the room*
> 2. to pass through or cause to pass through by osmosis or diffusion  *to permeate a membrane*

You could use the standard noun form, *permeation*. Or if you wanted a neologism that suggests a substance having this quality, you could try *permeatonium* or *permeatite*.

Comment: I actually quite like this suggestion. If nothing better is suggested,  I will accept this answer in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider ***percolate***.

> : [no object] (of a liquid or gas) filter gradually through a porous
>   surface or substance: *the water percolating through the soil may
>   leach out minerals*
>
> : (of information or an idea or feeling) spread gradually through an
>   area or group of people: *this issue has percolated into the public
>   consciousness*
>   [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/percolate)

Comment: Another fine suggestion that I might use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, though not exactly related to strengthening of bonds, it indicates kinship.

**Propinquity**

> noun
>
> 1. nearness in place; proximity.
> 2. **nearness of relation; kinship.**
> 3. affinity of nature; similarity.
> 4. nearness in time.